# Incomplete reply from the server alert message display with IE 8 browser

Tags: javascript, jsp, internet-explorer-8

In one of my `jsp` page having menu-bar, in that menu-bar i have three link which is

`:option1 || option 2 || option 3||`

when i first click on the option 1 or whet ever link ,

it will call the below  my strut-action using JavaScript only

```
window.location = "option1.action?Id="+Id;
```

It will load the my view page and in that page having the dhtmltreeloading and some dwr call which load some data in the page level div , 
while this process is running it  giving the alert message

and message should be like this :- `"Incomplete reply from server"`

can anybody having idea why this happen?

If anyone having the idea of root-cause/solution ,please share it with me

Answer (score 0):

I got my solution from the below link:
it is just hack, not a full solution 
http://directwebremoting.org/jira/browse/DWR-592?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin%3Aactivity-stream-issue-tab